# Reconnect client to different socket

Tags: sockets, delphi, tcp, indy, broker

I have a mobile client that will connect via TCP to a server. I'd like to set up a broker arrangement, where the client connects to the server on port 12345; the server authenticates the client and sends the client a socket to a server that handles that user's needs and tells the client to reconnect to the received socket. So instead of the client staying connected to 1.2.3.4:12345, I now want the client to connect to 1.2.3.4:23456.

Is there a way to do this within the TCP protocol? Or do I need to do custom programming on both sides of the connection?

Using TIdMappedPortTCP, I tried this:

```
procedure TForm3.idMapPortBeforeConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  if Pos(AContext.Binding.PeerIP,'192.168.0.21') > 0 then
    AContext.Binding.SetPeer('192.168.0.89',12345);
end;
```

This successfully changes the peer port to the desired port, but doesn't tell the client to reconnect. So the port mapping is still used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want at the TCP layer. Once a connection is established, its endpoints cannot be changed. To do what you want, the server needs to send a message to the client telling it the new IP/port, then the client needs to make a new TCP socket and connect it to that IP/port

Comment: Thanks Remy that's what I thought, just wanted to confirm.